# Access denied on S3 PUT request with pre-signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file directly to S3 bucket with pre-signed URL but getting AccessDenied (403 Forbidden) error on PUT request.

PUT request is allowed in bucket's CORS configuration.

Do I also need to update bucket policy with allowing `s3:PutObject`, `s3:PutObjectAcl` action?

P.S. Forgot to add. I already tried to add `s3:PutObject` and `s3:PutObjectAcl` with `Principal: *` and in this case uploading is working just fine, but how to restrict access for uploading? It's should be only available for pre-signed URL's, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I figured out how to fix it. Here are the steps:

1. Replace `Principal: *` with `"Principal": {"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::USER-ID:user/username"}`. Instead of `USER-ID:user/username` put desirable user credentials which you can find in Amazon IAM section. Read more about Principal here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html.
2. Be sure that the user which you specified in `Principal` has `s3:PutObject` and `s3:PutObjectAcl` permissions for a needed bucket.
3. Check your Lambda's function permissions. It also should have `s3:PutObject`, `s3:PutObjectAcl` for a needed bucket. You can check it on IAM Roles page (if you created separate role for a Lambda function) or through function Designer page (read only)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case (and maybe help others) the problem was that (due to a typo in SAM Template) the proper policy was not being apply **TO THE LAMBDA** that create the SignedUrl

It took me sometime because I thought the problem was in the Actual Uploading, while the real problem was really in creating the url (though s3 didnt say anything about Permission Problems...)

So, you can check if the S3CrudPolicy is applying to the currect Bucket and that may fix the issue for you.

Comment: I also experienced a problem where using a signed URL to upload an image to an S3 bucket returned a 403 error. To fix this, I gave the Lambda function, which generates the signed URL, write permissions for that bucket